# How do I pass data from Parse to UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Currently I have Parse data, which consists of images, titles, and price.

I want to fetch data and pass it to a UITableView, how would I do that?

Do I query all the data and set it to each UILabel?

Currently I have 4 labels, 1 ImageView and 3 TextLabel

Heres the code for my UITableViewController

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        queryProducts()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source


    func queryProducts() {

        var query = PFQuery(className:"product")
        query.whereKey("playerName", equalTo:"Sean Plott")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        // What should i put here?
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Here is the screenshot of the tableView storyboard

[image]

Again How do I pass all the Parse data to the tableView?

Comment: Simple solution is create model class having all these property as shown in xib(image,label,label,label) and inside in the for loop populate an array with these model class for each object in objects array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using Parse.com for a back-end data service.
Well it is easy to handle with data in this case,
just extend your TableViewController class from PFQueryTableViewController

```
class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {
 ////
}
```

Then follow those instructions in link below

SWIFT+PARSE data management :
[LINK](https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-swift-parse-com-tutorial-set-up-xcode-project-part-2-of-3-31a17d1c6581)

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass data to a UITableView. The table view asks for data to its **delegate**, which should be set to you View Controller. That's an IoC (Inversion of Control) in the sense that you don't give data to your control: you just set which object (the delegate) it's going to be responsible of feeding data to your TableView.

As you're extending from `UITableViewController`, probably your table view has **delegate** and **dataSource** properties already set. To check that, right-click Table View in Interface Builder: you should see those two outlets already set.

You need then to:

- create a property to store the result of your query:

  `var objects: [PFObject]?`
- override from [UITableView DataSource Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/)

  - `- numberOfSectionsInTableView:`. [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/numberOfSectionsInTableView:). Returning 1 if you only have one section.
  - `- tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`. The number of objects you get from Parse. `self.objects.count`
  - `- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`: you need to create a cell and populate the labels
- also, as you want your TableView to be reloaded when new data comes in, call `reloadData`